# Convert polygon to raster and give value to null cells

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, polygon, rasterization, nodata

Is there a way to **convert polygon features to raster while also populating null cells** with a specific value?  As in, can I create a raster from a polygon shapefile and have the tool populate all null cells with a value of zero (0)?  I'd like to do this because I will eventually sum several rasters using Raster Calculator, and it doesn't handle null values very well.

I know how to use the "Con(IsNull)" forumla in raster calculator to achieve this once the raster has been created, but would like to avoid having to perform this extra step if possible.

Comment: Can you draw a picture? If you want everything outside the polygon to be NULL and everything inside the polygon to have values derived from the polygon you can run the tool as normal and set the NoData value to 0 on the image, provided that 0 isn't a valid value within the data, if some of your polygons will have 0 as a value then this will need to be a two or three step process.. please indicate what valid values you will be encountering.

Comment: I'm unable to draw a picture, but I think you're on the right track.  My focus, or "study" area, is a circle with a 1-mile radius.  My polygons are service areas within that circle.  I'd like to create a raster that has values greater than zero for my polygons, and values of zero everywhere outside of my polygons, but within my 1-mile circle.

Comment: It seems like the best approach would be to run the "polygon to raster" tool and use my circle polygon shapefile as the processing extent, and also set the NoData values to zero.  Is this possible?

Comment: Feature to Raster http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00120000002v000000 will give you values inside the 1-mile and 0 outside, but that only affects the raster you're creating. Beware of your environment NoData setting http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001w00000043000000, that should be set to NONE. If that's not playing ball then set the NoData to MINIMUM, run the tool and then change the NoData in the raster dataset in catalog to maximum + 1 (must be unsigned data type).

Comment: Another good tool to use is GDAL_Rasterize http://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html, you can use that from QGIS if you have it. It's best to give it an existing raster already set to 0 (Create Constant Raster http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000s4000000) for cell size etc.. then it shouldn't affect the NoData setting for that raster..

Comment: Thanks, Michael.  I'll give those a try.  Appreciate the help!

Comment: You're not going to get a circle in a raster, meaning there's a distinction between outside the circle in the (rectangular) raster extents which is nodata, and inside the circle but not your polygons which should be 0. This is background vs true nodata in a raster. I think the easiest thing to do is incorporate your circle into your polygons as just another polygon and give it a zero value/attribute. That way when you rasterize the polygons, you'll get your zero pixels and nodata. It's not that rc doesn't handle them well, it's that any math involving null results in null.

Comment: Thanks, Chris.  One thing I forgot to mention is that I'm going to have to do this for dozens of polygon layers.  Incorporating the circle into each polygon layer is no problem, but it would be an iterative process.  Do you know of any way to do it in a more efficient manner?

Comment: I'm not much of a model builder/scripter yet, but it should be a fairly simple one depending on how the data is arranged. It would probably best be asked as a separate question. Is it the *same* circle or a 1m buffer around each point the service areas are generated from? If the same, a simple model that iterates on files in folder/feature classes in geodatabase and Appends the circle file to each is all it would take. Different circles would be more complicated. More details about your total workflow would be helpful (in a new question) to really optimize things.